# How can I query across multiple XML files, each contained within a ZIP, without extracting them?

Tags: xml, uri, xquery

I have a few thousand XML files, each contained within its own ZIP and I want to run an XQuery on all of these without having to extract any of the XML files.

I am able to make a path in my XQuery to query multiple XML files outside of a ZIP using the following:

```
in collection('file:///C:/Users/Desktop/All_completed_files?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')/standard
```

Is there any way I can amend the path above to query the files in a ZIP? If it's not as simple as changing the path, is there any recommendation as to how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this. It gives a lot of information regarding this scenario. https://icl.googleusercontent.com/?lite_url=http://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Get_zipped_XML_file&ei=UQAAiShE&lc=en-IN

Answer (score 0):

The answer is (for now) mostly dependent on the XQuery implementation you are using. Some (like BaseX) allow you to directly specify a ZIP file as argument of `fn:collection()`.